Android Work manager not making api call after app cleared from the background
I implemented work manager code. when I turn off device internet and hit the api call using work manager, request is in queue , now I cleared the app from background And again turn on the device internet but I am not able to get data on.
please let me know that will work manager make api call from previous request (which I made in offline mode and cleared app from background) when internet comes in device.
Will work manager make api call from offline mode and app cleared from the background

It depends on how you implemented the Worker. In general Workers can request a retry.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
